# How to set 24h time format in Grafana

Tags: grafana

in `grafana.ini` I have set

```
[date_formats]
full_date = YYYY-MMM-DD @ HH:mm:ss a
interval_second = HH:mm:ss a
interval_minute = HH:mm a
interval_hour = MMM DD HH:mm a
interval_day = MMM DD
interval_month = YYYY-MM
interval_year = YYYY
```

(ISO8601)
but in the time range selection there is still 'am' and 'pm'.

How can I remove this?

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! Try removing the `a` at the end of the time.

Comment: It works - thanks. As far I knew just capital `HH` instead of 'hh' like for `strftime()` in C and POSIX for that.

Comment: `HH` allows to the hours from `00` to `23`. The `a` determines whether `AM` or `PM` should be shown or not. That's why removing it works. Should I write an answer?

Comment: Well it solves the problem -> yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `a` at the end of the time indicates the part of the day AM or PM. Although you have changed the hours from `hh` to `HH` for 24h, keeping the `a` retains AM or PM. Removing it removes AM/PM.

Comment: The date formats in grafana.ini have syntax of https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/